# Getting error when adding new object with HTTP POST in .NETCore

Tags: asp.net-core, post, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new to .NetCore and Blazor. I am trying to do a POST of an new Anime, but I am allways getteing the error "The Genre field is required." I have added the `genreId` to the JSON Object but still the same error -> [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjrmI.png)

It's one to many relation, where one animal can have only one genre but one genre can have many enemies.

I don't know if it's useful but here are screenshots of my two tables in the DB -> [Anime table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9xqU.png) and the [Genre tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjYT2.png)

Here are my to Models:

Anime model

```
public class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CoverImage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Author { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public string Studio { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Genre model

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Anime> Animes { get; set; }
}
```

AnimeService where I am adding the new anime to the DB

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Anime>>> AddAnime(Anime NewAnime)
{
    ServiceResponse<List<Anime>> serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<List<Anime>>();

    _dataContext.Animes.Add(NewAnime);
    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    var animes = await _dataContext.Animes
        .Include(a => a.Genre)
        .ToListAsync();

    if (animes == null)
    {
        serviceResponse.Success = false;
        serviceResponse.Message = "Animes could be found!";
    }

    serviceResponse.Data = animes;

    return serviceResponse;
}
```

AnimeController

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddAnime")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<List<Anime>>>> AddAnime(Anime NewAnime)
{
    return Ok(await _animeService.AddAnime(NewAnime));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed on Discord:

You're using .NET 6 with nullables enabled.

As an Anime can exist before it has Genre assigned I would configure the tables like this:

```
public class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CoverImage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Author { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? GenreId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(GenreId))]
    public Genre? Genre { get; set; }

    public string Studio { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonIgnore]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Anime.Genre))]
    public List<Anime> Animes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Now, it just so happens that, for the UTC timezone (which Stack Overflow uses), it just became 12 AM, so since it changed the day, I can vote now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Anime instance don't habe a Genre object but it is requiered in your db context

You have to add navigation property GenreId as nullable if you think that Genre is optional

```
   public class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... another properties
    
   public int? GenreId { get; set; }
    public  virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

}
```

after this you will have to make a new database migration